# C++ in Eclipse—What's a toolchain?

Tags: c++, eclipse

In Eclipse, to build/run a C++ project, I needed to make Mac OS X GCC the default toolchain. What is a toolchain, and why did I have to do this?

Comment: [elinux.org/Toolchains](http://elinux.org/Toolchains)

Comment: Something has to compile the code you write, you know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't bring its own C++ compiler, so you have to specify it in preferences. And since compiler, linker and debugger depend more or less upon each other, these have to be specified too. That's what is called a *toolchain*: the set of tools (compiler, debugger, linker) that you want to use with eclipse.

You have to set up the toolchain because for most platforms there is more than one available.

Answer (score 1):

Toolchains are the required tools to successfully run a code.
A normal IDE support a large variety of toolchains (compiler, debugger, linker, etc) and since they need them to work to run the code you must specify them before.

**Note:**Its nit something eclipse specific but its a general term for IDEs